# Ternary operator inside an object in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React app, and I have a code segment that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';

let isZero = false;

class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        const { value } = this.props;

        isZero = false;
        if (value === 0) {
            isZero = true;
        }

        // removed for brevity
    }
}

const styles = {
    otherStyles: {
        minWidth: isZero ? '120px' : '60px',
        margin: '5px 5px 5px 0',
        lineHeight: isZero ? '120px' : '60px',
    },
};

export default Button;
```

But, apparently the conditional statement is not applied inside the object, as when `value` is 0, I still get the `60px` instead of `120px`. Any ideas?

Comment: The object is initializing when `isZero = false` (see at the beginning of your code). The object is not updated is `isZero` value changes

Comment: It's a **VERY BAD IDEA** to mutate variables inside the `render()` function.

Comment: I don't believe you're correct @d3L - it's a bad idea *only* if you mutate **states** not variables.

Comment: @James I stand corrected. You are right only mutating the state itself is bad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your styles are defined outside of render and hence are not calculated everytime the variable isZero change, define it inside your render if you want it to be dynamic

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';


class KeyPadButton extends Component {
    isZero = false;
    render() {
        const { click, disabled, value } = this.props;

        this.isZero = false;
        if (value === 0) {
            this.isZero = true;
            console.log(value);
            console.log(isZero);
            console.log(styles.buttonStyles);
            console.log(styles.otherStyles);
        }


    const styles = {
        buttonStyles: {
            float: 'left',
            width: this.isZero ? '120px' : '60px',
            height: this.isZero ? '120px' : '60px',
            border: '1px solid #f9f9f9',
            borderRadius: '5px',
        },
        otherStyles: {
            minWidth: this.isZero ? '120px' : '60px',
            margin: '5px 5px 5px 0',
            lineHeight: this.isZero ? '120px' : '60px',
        },
    };

        return (
            <RaisedButton label={value}
                          buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyles}
                          style={styles.otherStyles}
                          disabled={disabled}
                          onClick={() => click(value)}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default KeyPadButton;
```

Comment: is there a way using ternary operator such that width or height doesnt get set if this.isZero is false 

something like  this.isZero ? (width: '120px') :null

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is applied **at the time it is evaluated**.

That's before an instance of the class is created.

Move the `styles` constant **inside** the `render` function **after** you give `isZero` a value.